# Checking if time ranges overlap in PostgreSQL without separate Start and End fields

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgre which has room bookings stores as:

```
Room_id |   Meet_time  |
123456  | [9:00 - 10:00) |
```

I want to check if room 123456 is free from 9:30 to 10:00. How would I check that?

Comment: Is `meet_time` a `daterange`?

Comment: it's a timerange according to the table

Answer (score 1):

You can check overlapping of ranges with `&&` operator (see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)).
So to check all rooms which are free for given timerange, you can use this query:

```
select *
from <your table> as T
where not <given timerange> && T."Meet_time"
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d6082/4)</kbd>**